# Django doesn't load images from media

Tags: django

### I've set things for the setting and the URLs as follow but it doesn't load the images from media directory:

settings.py:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/media/')
```

---

```
urls.py:
urlpatterns = [
    path('create/', views.image_create, name='create'),
    path('detail/<int:id>/<slug:slug>/', views.image_detail, name='detail'),
]
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,
                          document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

---

this is the link generated for the page: https://127.0.0.1:8000/images/detail/1/django-and-duke/
and the link for the image: https://127.0.0.1:8000/media/images/2020/08/02/django-and-duke.jpg

I have another app named accounts and if I add the base URL of account to the first of this media URLs it works! but I know they are separated from each other.
if you need other parts of code please tell me.

Comment: Thanks guys. I found the problem. I had added MEDIA_URL and MEDIA_ROOT inside one of my apps not inside the main URL.py file of project.

Comment: Does your 'media' directory exists in Base directory too? can you show your project structure? also try editing this line `MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/media/')` to `MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')`

Answer (score 0):

Remove the slashes in `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/media/')`

If any argument to `os.path.join` begins with a slash `/` it will overwrite all previous arguments. You're currently setting `MEDIA_ROOT` to be `/media/`

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```